# Python API using User Account to use User GCP Services (Storage, Engines, etc)

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know if I can create an python API that receives username and password from a Google user and has access to Google services from that user.

ex:
User gives me google email and password and I can move files between user GCP buckets

If there is no way to do this directly, I would like to know ways to perform this operation without a frontend, only with the user's email and password

Comment: If the users are in an organization that uses Google Workspace, you can create a service account a with domain wide delegation options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the password for a Google Account via an API.

Your question:

> I would like to know if I can create an python API that receives
> username and password from a Google user and has access to Google
> services from that user.

Yes, you could create a Python API that asks the user to enter their username and password. That is easy to do via an HTTP form.

However, even with the username and password, Google security would quickly block the account. All authentication is browser-based for user identities and requires a **human** to interact with the browser.